# How to store record changes in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables that stores pricing for a product --

```
`product`
- id
- name
- added_date
- is_removed (BOOL)

`price`
- id
- product_id
- price
- price_type
- added_date
- is_removed (BOOL)
```

These tables always reflect the current status of the product as it is live on the store.

However, for auditing purposes I need to keep track of the following five events:

- A new product is added (new product_id, or is_removed 1==>0)
- A product is removed (is_removed=1)
- A new price is added (new price_id or is_removed 1==>0)
- A price is removed (is_removed=1)
- A price is changed (price +-)

What would be the best way to keep track of this? It would be very difficult to do this at the application level, since there are about 30 ways that these two tables can change. I was thinking of using someone like a trigger to add a log to another table, though I'm afraid that would be a big hit to these tables that are quite active (~10M writes per day).

What would be the best solution for this? Note that the tables are InnoDB.

Comment: Does the updates to these table happen in batches (particular time a day) or anytime randomly. Also suppose one product price is changed 3 - 4 times within short duration, then in that case, do you want to audit all the changes or just the latest.

Comment: @Utsav -- these aren't really in batches, but throughout the day 7 days a week. It would be extremely, extremely rare for an item to change more than one time per day.

Comment: Is setting up a master-slave replication an option for you here? Can you change current table schema?

Comment: @StanMcGeek I suppose setting up master-slave would be an option, but we cannot change the current schema on the two above tables (though we could add additional tables if needed).

Comment: Well, then, considering your load (~10M writes/day), your only viable option is setting up master-slave and applying your initial trigger-based solution on a slave. I've encountered similar problem a few times and as far as I know there are no "perfect" solutions to this, master-slave with triggers worked out well for me. I've came up with few others at that time, but they all require either a change of schema or migration to other dbms, which are usually not an option. I don't post this as an answer, because it isn't in my opinion, hopefully, someone will propose something more useful

Comment: How about create a new table say S. Sync data from Product P to S once. Then everyday compare data between P and S and find the changed records and populate the audit table with this. Then sync S with P again. (i m just using Product in example. You can do same for Price or use a denormatized table to contain both.)

Only downside here would be the scenario where the price change more than once in a day, then you cannot capture that. Also the overhead of one extra table but it would be lot better than trigger.

Comment: @Utsav -- this is an interesting idea. Could you please show a basic code example of how you mean 'compare'?

Comment: @David542  Added answer with basic flow. Let me know in case something is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 tables. One to hold delta(changed) records and another to hold previous day's snapshot from Core tables. In given example, I am only using Product table but you can extend the example for Price too.

1. (One time process). Create another table say `S` and synct data from
   Product (`P`) in it.
2. From next day, compare `P` and `S` and find the
   changed/new records. You can do it by left outer join.

   ```
   select p.id,p.name,p.added_date,p.is_removed,
   case when S.id is null then 'Insert' 
   else when S.name <> P.name or S.added_date <> P.added_date or S.is_removed <> P.is_removed
   then 'Update'
   else 'No Change' end as RecordStatus
   from Product P
   left outer join S
   on P.id=S.id
   ```
3. Now you can use this result to enter records in another table say Audit. You can use a surrogate key and date column to keep track of these records in Audit on daily basis
4. Sync `S` with `P` at the end. (from next day repeat from step 2)

Comment: got it, thanks for the clear explanation. This might be a silly question to ask, but is it possible to trigger the script on a pre-defined interval within mysql? Or is it required to put it on a shell/cron job?

Comment: @David542 sure, there's this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html and in case you need to do an external system call (i.e. execute some script), you can use some kind of UDF like lib_mysqludf_sys